# WebApi routing issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am using the default routing setup in WebApiConfig (MVC 4) but for some reason I am getting unexpected results.

If I call `/api/devices/get/` it hits the `Get` function but the `Id` is "get" rather than `1`.  If I call `/api/devices/get/1` I get a 404. I also want to be able to support multiple parameters i.e.

```
public Device[] Get(int? page, int? pageSize) // for multiple devices
```

**The route**

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
}
```

**And my API:**

```
public class DevicesController : ApiController
{
    EClient client = new EClient();

    // GET api/devices/5
    public Device Get(string id)
    {
        return client.GetDeviceBySerial(id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

id in the controller parameter should be integer:

```
public Device Get(int id)
{
    return client.GetDeviceBySerial(id);
}
```

if you need to pass in string, or other prams, just use quesry string:

```
public Device Get(int id, string pageSize)
{
    return client.GetDeviceBySerial(id);
}
```

the above can be called as:

/api/devices/1

or

/api/devices/?id=1&pageSize=10

Note: you do not need to specify method name. Web API will judge that on the basis of HTTP Verb used. If its a GET request, it will use the Get method, if its a POST request, then it will use Post method ... and so on.

You can change the above behavior, but I guess you mentioned that you want to keep usign the default Routing ... so I am not covering that.